# How to create a new class instance from within an instance?

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to write a small "life simulation", where the lifeforms can reproduce themselves.
I want each class instance to be able to create more instances, like cloning/reproducing itself.
I do know how to create a new instance from outside the class, but I'd like the class to do it by itself.

```
class Life{

    constructor(){
        this.age = 0;
    }

    frame_loop(){
        this.age ++;

        if (this.age == 18){
            this.reproduce();
        }
    }

    reproduce(){
        // obviously does not work
        this.new();
    }

}

let bacteria = new Life();
```

I don't want to create the new life from outside the class, like

```
let bacteria1 = new Life();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you're having a syntax error here: `class Life()` <-- parenthesis should be omitted. Is it a typo or..? Anyway, you can simply `return new Life();`: https://jsfiddle.net/gn8d70ts/ . What should `reproduce` do, though?

Comment: You're right, cheers. Corrected. I created this simplified code example for this question to make the problem easier to digest :)

Comment: should `reproduce` create a **new instance** and override it to the existing one or should the new instance be stored as a child of the current one?

Comment: @briosheje: thank you for your example. In your code example, the "reproduction" is called "manually" from outside the class. I'm looking for a solution where the class itself "decides" to create a new class.

Comment: it can be called inside it as well, you just need to invoke `frame_loop` 18 times. https://jsfiddle.net/gn8d70ts/1/ Please explain **the desired outout**, so that we can further help you.

Comment: Are you sure you want a class and not an object? The purpose of classes is being invoked and replicated with different context variables. Don't watch languages like Java where classes are the only construct to build every concept. JavaScript is different and the use of a class, to me, appears wrong

Comment: Thank you @briosheje, I will take a thorough look into your guidance and come back if I still have problems. So far, the "return new Life()" was a great hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. have a children property and whenever the age is right new Life() is created

```js
class Life{
    children = [];
    constructor(){
        this.age = 0;
    }

    frame_loop(){
        this.age ++;

        if (this.age == 18){
            this.reproduce();
        }
    }

    reproduce(){
        console.log("new life")
        this.children.push(new Life());
    }

}

let bacteria = new Life();
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  bacteria.frame_loop();
}
```